# What are all the Authentic Tantra Scriptures accepted by the Srikula branch of Shaktism?

Tags: scripture, tantra, devi, shaktism, sri-vidya

Can someone list all the authentic Tantra Scriptures that are accepted by the Srikula Branch of Shaktism?